LaTeX Tabular - centering Nice Tabular

It is my first time using tables in LaTeX and after discovering the nicematrix package, I didn't find a way to center this quite long table.
Tried centering but it only worked superficially. Thanks in advance!
{\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}c!{\quad}ccc!{\quad}ccc!{\quad}ccc!{\quad}ccc!{\quad}ccc@{}}
\toprule
Longueur du fil ($m$) & \Block{1-3}{0.3} & & & \Block{1-3}{0.4} & & & \Block{1-3}{0.5} & & & \Block{1-3}{0.6} & & & \Block{1-3}{0.7} \\
\midrule
 \Block{2-1}{Demi-periode ($s$)}& 0.5543 &0.5547 &0.5683 & 0.6629 & 0.6657 & 0.6597 & 0.6536 & 0.6557 & 0.6454& 0.7984 & 0.8007 & 0.7994& 0.8757 & 0.8753 & 0.8727\\
  & 0.5497& 0.5506 & 0.5232 & 0.5988 & 0.5967 & 0.5944 & 0.7177 & 0.7478 & 0.7507& 0.7287 & 0.7364 & 0.7414& 0.7413 & 0.7765 & 0.7667 \\
  \midrule
Period ($s$)& 1.1040 & 1.1053& 1.0915 & 1.2617& 1.2624& 1.2541& 1.3713& 1.4035& 1.3961& 1.5271 & 1.5371 & 1.5408& 1.6170 & 1.6518 & 1.6394\\ 
  \midrule
Periode moyenne ($s$)& \Block{1-3}{1.1002} & & & \Block{1-3}{1.2594} & & & \Block{1-3}{1.3903} & & & \Block{1-3}{1.5350} & & & \Block{1-3}{1.6360} \\
\midrule 
Periode moyenne carée ($s^2$) & \Block{1-3}{1.1210} & & & \Block{1-3}{1.5860} & & & \Block{1-3}{1.9329} & & & \Block{1-3}{2.3562} & & & \Block{1-3}{2.6767} \\

\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}\par}


Welcome to TeX.SE. Do I see correctly that you're trying to fit a table with 16 columns on a page?

Yes It's for a paper and I don't want to use word :D

You might be better off with changing the layout of the table. Maybe flipping rows and columns would make more sense? 5 columns should be easier to fit in a page than 16.

or you could rotate the table.

Apparently your table is to wide that can be fit in text block or even on page. Consequently it spill-out on right page border.
You not provide any information about your document page layout.
What you can do, are suggested in comments below your question. Beside them, you can do the following not very advisable hack:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=20mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\footnotesize\centering%
\begin{tblr}{colsep=2pt,
             colspec = {@{} X[c,m] @{\quad } ccc @{\quad } ccc @{\quad } ccc @{\quad } ccc @{\quad } ccc @{}},
             cell{1}{2} = {c=15}{c},
             cell{2,Y,Z}{2,5,8,11,14} = {c=3}{},
             cell{3}{1} = {r=2}{},
             }
\toprule
    &
Longueur du fil ($m$) 
    &       & & &       & & &       & & &       & & &       & &     \\
\cmidrule[lr]{2-16}
    &   0.3 & & &   0.4 & & &   0.5 & & &   0.6 & & &   0.7 & &     \\
\cmidrule[r]{1-1}
\cmidrule[lr]{2-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-7}\cmidrule[lr]{8-10}\cmidrule[lr]{11-13}\cmidrule[lr]{14-16}
Demi-periode ($s$)
    & 0.5543 & 0.5547 & 0.5683 & 0.6629 & 0.6657 & 0.6597 & 0.6536 & 0.6557 & 0.6454 & 0.7984 & 0.8007 & 0.7994 & 0.8757 & 0.8753 & 0.8727 \\
    & 0.5497 & 0.5506 & 0.5232 & 0.5988 & 0.5967 & 0.5944 & 0.7177 & 0.7478 & 0.7507 & 0.7287 & 0.7364 & 0.7414 & 0.7413 & 0.7765 & 0.7667 \\
  \midrule
Period ($s$)
    & 1.1040 & 1.1053 & 1.0915 & 1.2617 & 1.2624 & 1.2541 & 1.3713 & 1.4035 & 1.3961 & 1.5271 & 1.5371 & 1.5408 & 1.6170 & 1.6518 & 1.6394 \\ 
  \midrule
Periode moyenne ($s$)
    &   1.100   & & &   1.2594  & & &   1.3903  & & &   1.5350  & & &   1.6360  \\
\midrule 
Periode moyenne carée ($s^2$) 
    &   1.1210  & & &   1.5860  & & &   1.9329  & & &   2.3562  & & &   2.6767  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


The similar result you can obtain using nicematrix package (I'm not very familiar with it, so I use tblr of tabularray package) or with tabularx package.
As you can see, suggested formatting of table has smaller font size, enable to break text in the first column into two lines, and has assumed, that text borders are 20mm wide.
